# PostgreSQL - Recovery process triggering after startup

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I m trying to run PostgreSQL 9.5 on Ubuntu 16.04. Our PostreSQL setup looks as following:

PostgreSQL Primary (9.5 on Ubuntu 16.04, Docker container) --rsync--> Walstore (backup server, Docker Container) --rsync--> PostgreSQL Standby (v9.5 on Ubuntu 16.04, Docker container).

In case of Primary crashes we are going to copy the Standby PostgreSQL data (which is in sync with Primary PostgreSQL data, excluding only recovery.conf file) to Primary PostgreSQL data directory and startup Primary PostgreSQL server again.

After the Primary PostgreSQL server is up and running again, a recovery process is going to be triggered as follow (logs):

```
postgresql-docker-primary-1   |  * Starting PostgreSQL 9.5 database server
postgresql-docker-primary-1   |    ...done.
postgresql-docker-primary-1   | 2022-11-28 10:14:59 UTC [27-1] LOG:  database system was shut down in recovery at 2022-11-28 10:11:14 UTC
postgresql-docker-primary-1   | 2022-11-28 10:14:59 UTC [27-2] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
postgresql-docker-primary-1   | 2022-11-28 10:14:59 UTC [27-3] LOG:  redo starts at 0/1700DB8
postgresql-docker-primary-1   | 2022-11-28 10:14:59 UTC [27-4] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/3000060
postgresql-docker-primary-1   | 2022-11-28 10:14:59 UTC [27-5] LOG:  redo done at 0/3000028
postgresql-docker-primary-1   | 2022-11-28 10:14:59 UTC [27-6] LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2022-11-28 10:04:37.388433+00
postgresql-docker-primary-1   | 2022-11-28 10:14:59 UTC [27-7] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
postgresql-docker-primary-1   | 2022-11-28 10:14:59 UTC [26-1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgresql-docker-primary-1   | 2022-11-28 10:14:59 UTC [31-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
postgresql-docker-primary-1   | 2022-11-28 10:14:59 UTC [34-1] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
```

Since the Standby PostgreSQL data is in sync with PostgreSQL Primary data, why the Primary startup triggers the automatic recovery? My expectation is that the Primary PostgreSQL database server is not going to perform an automatic recovery. How does PostgreSQL know that a recovery process has to be triggered or not?
In our production case the automatic recovery would take around 3 hours in our case, so that the PostgreSQL server would be unavailable for around 3 hours and we would like to avoid this behaviour.

Is there any documentation where I can find the recovery process triggering of PostgreSQL database server?

Thank you very much for your feedback.
ctn

Comment: Your description is not adequate.  Is rsync being run while the database are shutdown?  In recovery mode?  What are the options given to it?

Comment: Sorry not to provide all the infos. 
The archive_command is used to perform the rsync from primary to walstore e.g.
`archive_mode = on`
`archive_command = '<path>/sync_to_walstore.sh %p %f'`

**sync_to_walstore.sh:**
`rsync -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i <path>/walstore-access" -a $1` `root@$WAL_STORE_IP:<path>/$2`

The restore_command is used to perform the sync from walstore to standby server, e.g. 
**recovery.conf:**
`standby_mode = 'on'`
`restore_command = '<path>/restore_command.sh %f %p'`

Comment: In case of primary shutdown rsync with archive_command does not run whereas the rsync with restore_command will run until we shutdown standby server manually.

Comment: "going to copy the Standby PostgreSQL data...to Primary PostgreSQL data directory"  Is this copy done with the standby being shut down?

Comment: Yes, the standby is shut down while copying the data from standby to primary.

Comment: If the standby was shut down cleanly before copying, the copy should not go through recovery upon startup, unless the copy is trying to start up in standby mode.  If it were shutdown uncleanly (stop immediate) before copying, then it would be expected to go through recovery, but I wouldn't expect it to take hours.

Comment: I am running the following command to shutdown standby gracefully:
`$PGAPP/pg_ctl stop -w --mode=smart --pgdata=$PGDATA/pgdata ` `docker stop pg-primary` and copy the data directory from Standby to Primary, but the recovery is still triggered at Primary startup. Can it be that somehow the graceful shutdown is not going to be handled correctly at docker since I am using Docker compose for reproducing the issue?

Comment: @jjanes to use the standby data on primary I have to perform the following command to promote the standby and then copying the standby data to primary data directory:
`$PGAPP/pg_ctl promote --pgdata=$PGDATA`

In this case the recovery process won't be triggered on Primary startup. I m wondering if that the right approach? Thank you.